# How to programmatically get edit permission to realtime api file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am unable to give a user, programmatically, permission to edit a file that uses realtime API.

I can however go to the [docs.google.com](http://docs.google.com) and share that file with that user and in that case we can collaborate normally.

The difference between when I give permission programmatically and through [docs.google.com](http://docs.google.com) is that through the former one I see that permission is `can view` and in the latter one the permission is `can edit`.

When setting permission programmatically I have tried to set the role to all of the three possibilities `writer`, `owner` and `reader` but in all cases the final permission is only `can view`.

This is my JavaScript code for granting permission:

```
function insertPermission(fileId, value, type, role) {
  var body = {
    'value': value,
    'type': type,
    'role': role
  };
  var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
    'fileId': fileId,
    'sendNotificationEmails':true,
    'resource': body
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {console.log(resp); });
}

var value = 'Email of the user that is to get access';
    var type = 'user'; 
    var role = 'writer';
    var fileIdP = fileId;
    insertPermission(fileIdP,value,type,role);
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing there at a glance.  Did you try duplicating the request you are trying to send on the "Try It" page here?https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert  You can compare what your http request looks like to the one it sends.

Comment: @CherylSimon   Thank you so much for the quick answer. That pointed me to the right direction to debbuging the code. The problem was I gave the wrong 'role' input to the insertPermission() function. That role variable had it's value set to 'read'. Again thank you.